# When renaming file in Backgroundworker, file is "being used by another process"

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The majority of C# SO questions about this error involve Streamwriter. I don't believe this question is related.

I have a WinForms application. The app spawns a backgroundworker to do the real work (image processing) to stay responsive. In one function, I attempt to rename all image files in a directory (without opening them). I receive the error "**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**" I can't track down the source of the error.

In MainForm (form) class - spawn the backgroundworker:

```
private void b_preprocessImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgw_preprocessor.IsBusy == false)
        {
            bgw_preprocessor.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else 
        {...}
    }
```

Still in MainForm class - DoWork method for backgroundworker:

```
private void bgw_preprocessor_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        ImagePreprocessor preprocessor = new ImagePreprocessor();
        preprocessor.SetImageDirectoryPath(path);
        preprocessor.PreprocessImages(worker);    
    }
```

Inside ImagePreprocessor class - method that the backgroundworker runs:

```
public void PreprocessImages(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        this.worker = worker;

        if (!Directory.Exists(SourceImageDirectoryPath))
            return;
        else
        {...}

        if (!AreAllImagesValid())
            return;
        else
        {...}

        print.PrintLine("Renaming files...");
        AutoRenameAllImages();
```

Inside ImagePreprocessor class - method to rename images:

```
public void AutoRenameAllImages()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            // sourceImageFiles[] is an array of strings
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(sourceImageFiles[i]);
            string newName = Path.Combine(SourceImageDirectoryPath, "src_" + i.ToString() + f.Extension);
            print.PrintLine("Renaming " + f.Name + " to " + (new FileInfo(newName)).Name);

            try
            {
                f.MoveTo(newName);
                //File.Move(sourceImageFiles[i], newName);   // doesn't work either
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The error is immediately encountered upon trying to rename the first file. As far as I can tell, none of the files in question are open in any other applications. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use the handle command line tool to see what processes have a hold on the files. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx

Comment: This problem is most likely you have used this file somewhere **in your app**, not other app. And you forget to close it.

Comment: I simply do not have code for opening any files -- so far, only getting file names, counting files, renaming them, etc. @Cobster I will see what I can find out with that handle tool.

Comment: How do you check images are valid by `AreAllImagesValid`? Do you simply check by their file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can delete the file with the IDE open.  If you cannot close the IDE and try deleting the file again.  If it works the file is being held open by the IDE.  This usually happens if you break the code while it is running or forgot to close the file.

I'm not saying this will fix the issue but it will rule out the IDE and debugging as the problem.

I've seen this happen before.

Comment: I am able to delete the file with Visual Studio open. However, when I run the program and break on the error, I cannot manually delete it (file is open in vshost32.exe). I do not have any explicit code for opening any files.

Comment: That means the file was opened with visual studio whether by your code or a call like file move and was not closed properly.  You will have to close the IDE to release the file.

Comment: Many of the calls open the file even though you  don't know they do.

for example,  File.Moveto works the way I think it copies the file and deletes the old one so the file gets opened.

before there was move we did a copy and delete manually